# SSL JMS Jmeter test

Tags: java, jmeter, jms, tibco

I am trying to send JMS message to TIBCO queues using ssl through JMS
point-to-point sampler.I have downloaded the latest version of JMeter.

I have imported keystore certificates through SSL manager.

The provider URL is ssl://abc.com:63111

When I send the message, I get the error message like

Response message: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to query JNDI: Failed to connect to the server at tcp://abc.com:63111 [Root exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to connect to the server at tcp://abc.com:63111]

Why is it that ssl://abc.com:63111 gets converted to tcp://abc.com:63111

Comment: Can you show your sampler configuration ?

Comment: Can you show your factory.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved and the issue is due to the following below issue 

1) The Soap Action is defined wrong, so i corrected the soap Action.
2) The tibco queue was details are checked with the tibco team 
3) The library are kept in the jmeter lib folder and certificate details are updated in the system.properties of jmeter.

After doing above i am able to connect to the tibco queue.


Hope this will help someone.